# Как выбрать выбрать определенные столбцы DataFrame в pandas, используя список булевых переменных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame с N столбцами и список булевых переменных длинной N. Как получить DataFrame, такой что в него входят только те столбцы исходного DataFrame'а, которым в списке булевых переменных соответствует True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df.loc[:, boolean_list]
```